# Controlling dynamically created containers

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Forgive me, I'm new to Flash Builder 4 and Actionscript 3 (actually, to programming as a whole beyond some very simplistic stuff).  I have watched / read a bunch of tutorials, and started a project but now seem to have hit a wall.  The answer is most likely simple, but seems to be alluding me.

How do I (or What approach should I take) to control visual elements, for instance, BorderContainer's, that I created dynamically?

As is, I have an Application containing a BorderContainer and a DataGrid.  At runtime, 3 new BorderContainers (which are dragable, and resizeable) are created based on XML data that contains X & Y co-ordinates, and Height and Width values, and then added to the pre-existing BorderContainer.  How would I go about getting the properties of these children BorderContainers to be displayed and remain up-to-date in the DataGrid (such as when they are moved/resized)?

My intentions in the future would be to have a custom component which displays a summary of these items in a separate area (think photoshop "layers" control, but much more simplistic), but wanted to get a better understanding of what's going on first.

Any input, documentation, examples, etc. is all appreciated.  Again, I apologize for what may be an incredibly easy solution, or if any of my language is unclear, I'm new to this ^_^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an ArrayCollection of the BorderContainers with their various properties set (also make sure you call addElement on the parent BorderContainer).  Make sure your ArrayCollection is declared as Bindable, then set it as the dataProvider for your DataGrid.  Then specify the columns for your DataGrid based on whatever properties you want to display (height, width, etc).  Now whenever the properties of the BorderContainers change, the DataGrid will automatically update.

Comment: Thanks Wade.  I did as you indicated, and although it introduced more bugs into the DataGrid, and added a bit more confusion for how I want to proceed, it did resolve the problem and gave me more to work on.  Let the learning experience continue!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a pure AS3 project, the best approach is to build a dictionary of your objects.

Let's also assume you've created identifiers for the components, or can easily create them at runtime.

```
var containers:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

private function _init():void
{
  //some loop to create objects
  containers[newObject.name] = newObject;
}
```

Later you can quickly access it by just grabbing the hashed index from the containers dictionary.

Now, assuming a Flex project, we have a few more approaches we can take:

- DisplayObjectContainer implements getChildByName()
- Group implements getElementAt, and numElements to iterate over, check names, and return value expected.

Personally, I still prefer the dictionary approach...

As for keeping things up to date, you can look into Binding (typically a Flex-only solution) or more appropriately investigate the events dispatched:

- Event.RESIZE
- Event.MOVE
- etc.

In the handlers, just update your UI!

HTH, otherwise post more info and we'll see what we can figure out.

Comment: I went with Wade Mueller's solution to this problem as it was a simple implementation of another ArrayCollection which I've already been dealing with.  However, I did want to thank you for introducing the Dictionary, as I intend to play around with it in the future.  Thanks!